# code coverage : Jest passing callback as parameter

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
HandleSubmit(){
    this.props.reset({}, () => {
        this.setState({
            userError: ''
        });
    });
}
```

how do i mock reset function of props in jest, 
I have tried `reset=jest.fn({},()=>{})` but its throwing this error:

> TypeError: specificMockImpl.apply is not a function

Answer (score 0):

write the reset function as independent then call that function inside handleSubmit.

```
HandleSubmit(){
    this.props.reset({},this.reset)
}
```

and it will be easy to test.